# Can we execute some queries while traversing resultset in java

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to implement a task in java using JDBC like Stored Procedure in SQL.
In SQL, when we write cursor, first we execute select query and then fetching the records we perform some actions.

Likely I have fired a select query in Hive.

```
sql="SELECT a,c,b FROM tbl_name";
res=stmt.executeQuery();    -----------> CONTAINS 30 RECORDS
while(res.next())
{
     sql="INSERT INTO table .....";
     rs1=stmt.executeQuery();

     sql="SELECT d,e,f FROM table .....";
     rs1=stmt.executeQuery();
     like wise many queries are there.....
.
.
.
..
}
```

As my select query contains 30 records but when I execute it   my while(res.next()) execute only once.

But instead of queries I just try to display field to check whether it is fetching or not
then it is working fine..
(while loop contains only System.out.println statements)

```
sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
res=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

while(res.next())
{
   S.O.P.("fields : "+res.getString(0));
}
```

(I think that when the resultset is getting traversed and if in between queries are there then queries get the executed but at the same time loop also get executes and after some time when queries execution get finishes by that while loop of resultset also get finishes and hence it get executes for once.   I am not sure about it.)

Why it is happening I am not getting. Is anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Each `Statement` can only have one open `ResultSet` at a time. From the documentation:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

The calls to `executeQuery` inside your loop will implicitly close the outer `ResultSet`, so that's why you only see one row.

Comment: I tried this also but still the execution is same (executing only one time. I cross check that whether result resultset itself contains 1 row. I check that query and it is giving me 30 rows as output).

Comment: I have tried with different statement and resultset object, but it seems that the inner statement execution closes the outer result set. The problem is solved when I create the inner statement using a new connection object. I would like to know whether it is advisable to create different connection objects while iterating through a result set.

Comment: You can reuse the same `Connection` object to create multiple `Statements` returning multiple `ResultSet`s.

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure your flow. Primarily, don't try and reuse the same `Statement` object to execute a new query. When I try that using the PostgreSQL driver, for example, I readily get an exception, "This ResultSet is closed."

Instead, rewrite it to something like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
Statement outerStatement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet outerResultSet = outerStatement.executeQuery("...");

while (outerResultSet.next()) {
    Statement innerStatement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet innerResultSet = innerStatement.executeQuery("...");
    while (innerResultSet.next()) {
        // ...
    }
    innerResultSet.close();
    innerStatement.close();
}
outerResultSet.close();
outerStatement.close();
conn.close();
```

Of course, surround with `try-catch-finally` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen like that, You can try until your query gets executed loop will wait.

Comment: I did this kind of task previously and it was fine. Now I am getting this kind of problem. Dont know why???  I check each and every thing many times but not getting.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you can only have one statement executing at one moment in time against one database connection so you can either create and execute the second statement, or iterate through the resultset from first statement and store the data in collection (e.g. in an arraylist of hashmap) then close that statement and run the second one, this time retrieving the id's from the collection you saved them in.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to have multiple statements open against a single connection. JDBC just doesn't support having multiple `ResultSet`s open for a single `Statement`. You don't need to open a whole new connection to have a second query; just create a new `Statement` and use that.